# .Net Core dependency injection - how to correctly resolve services in a loop at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

While I know how to inject dependencies using IoC container through constructors, I am having a hard time grasping the proper way (without using anti-patterns) of injecting new/more services at runtime.

Lets say I've got following code (simplified, but I actually have similar implementation and want to refactor it to use DI):

```
class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public ClassA(ILogger<ClassA> logger)
    ...
    public void Foo()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            var classA = new ClassA();
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I register the services with Host:

```
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                ...
                services.AddScoped<IClassA, ClassA>();
                ...
            });
```

I've read a lot of articles on the web and MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) and worked out that I can resolve ClassA in the while loop by:

**1.** Using IServiceScopeFactory (after injecting it into ClassA):

```
using IServiceScope scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();           
var classA = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IClassA>();
```

This approach however, seems to be regarded as anti-pattern (not sure why since the dependencies are still being resolved by the IoC container and Microsoft presents this in documentation)

**2.** I can wrap above in the factory class, register it with the container, inject into ClassA and return the service from there:

```
var classA = classAFactory.GetClassA();
```

In factory class I would still be using `IServiceScopeFactory` and will have to create additional factory class : interface pair.

**3.** Create factory class as above but instead of using `IServiceScopeFactory` inside factory, do:

```
return new ClassA();
```

Which of these approaches should I prefer, or is there other, better pattern to request services in a loop/at runtime?

Comment: A factory is the correct answer here - who told you that approach 1 was an anti-pattern?

Comment: People claim it's Service Locator pattern which is anti-pattern - usually in comments under articles about DI around web.

Comment: Whilst they are similar, there's a distinct difference in that a service locator is usually a static type and doesn't require injection before it can be used to resolve services (or it may be injected but it will be the only parameter in the constructor). In your case, your factory requires injection and therefore the container is responsible for wiring up dependencies. Control is still inverted - i.e. what's required to construct a valid instance of your type is presented in the constructor, rather than hidden within an implementation detail/method body. There is somewhat a blurred line tho.

Comment: That's what I thought, but thanks for clarification! So in above case, I can simply create scope using IServiceScopeFactory, and then keep resolving services from there. I understand that I don't have to go as far as example 2 - which is wrapping IServiceScopeFactory in another custom factory class, unless I'd like to have additional logic to be executed at runtime. Am I right?